# How can i import an exist image to a storagepool using libvirt?

Tags: libvirt

When I redeploy the libvirt project in other machines, I have to import the image(volume) created in other machines to the new storagepool. But, it seems that the libvirt api does not have the corresponding function? 
How can I import an existing image(volume) to a storagepool using libvirt API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the API, then the approach is to use `virStorageVolCreate` to create an empty image, and then `virStorageVolUpload` to stream content into the image.

If you're using trying to duplicate image files from one machine to another though, it might be easier to just copy them across outside libvirt (eg using scp), and then use `virStorgePoolRefresh` (via `virsh pool-refresh poolname`) to make libvirt aware of the copy you did.

Comment: The function should be "virStorageVolUpload" instead of  "virStoragePoolUpload" . (https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-storage.html#virStorageVolUpload)